# npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0

Tags: node.js, npm, extjs, npm-install

Getting the error

npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0

Things I tried:
Remove packagelock.json file
Remove node modules folder
do npm install.

But nothing seems to work.
Any suggestions?